# Use a singnal as an input or output in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I write this code . I want to use data as an output when r = '1' and input when w = '1'. I try inout but it doesn't work. and it had an error (Error: D:/modelism project/project/memory.vhd(42): Target of signal assignment is not a signal.). Can you help me to fix it ?

```
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Entity memory is
    Generic (bits: integer := 16;
         words: integer := 16);
    port (  r, w: in std_logic;-------read and write------------
        addr: in std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
        data: inout std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0));

End memory;
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Architecture memory of memory is
    Type vector_array is array (0 to words-1) of std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0);
    constant memory: vector_array :=
                    ( "0000000000000000",
                      "0000000000000001",
                      "0000000000000010",
                      "0000000000000011",
                      "0000000000000100",
                      "0000000000000101",
                      "0000000000000110",
                      "0000000000000111",
                      "0000000000000000",
                      "0000000000000001",
                      "0000000000000010",
                      "0000000000000011",
                      "0000000000000100",
                      "0000000000000101",
                      "0000000000000110",
                      "0000000000000111");
    signal loc: integer range 0 to words - 1;
begin
    process(r, w)
    begin
        if(r = '1') then
            loc <= to_integer(signed(addr));
            data <= memory(loc);
        elsif(w = '1') then
            loc <= to_integer(signed(addr));
            memory(loc) <= data;
        end if;
    end process;
End memory;
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the inout. The problem is because you're trying to assign memory which is a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you declare constant, it is a fixed value. you cannot change it later.
instead you can declare the memory as signal and declare an init constant to initialized it like below:

```
constant init: vector_array :=
                ( "0000000000000000",
                  "0000000000000001",
                  "0000000000000010",
                  "0000000000000011",
                  "0000000000000100",
                  "0000000000000101",
                  "0000000000000110",
                  "0000000000000111",
                  "0000000000000000",
                  "0000000000000001",
                  "0000000000000010",
                  "0000000000000011",
                  "0000000000000100",
                  "0000000000000101",
                  "0000000000000110",
                  "0000000000000111");
signal memory: vector_array := init;
```

Also, you need to be careful with ports from ***inout*** type that they should have a value assigned to them.

think about what happens when r='0' and w='0'??

Answer (score 0):

Implementing an "inout" pin could be done with a tri-state buffer. To do this you can describe it without a process because it has nothing to do with a "clock" or time but depends on the stationary value of another signal.

something like this:

when the "pin_we" is '1' then "pin_Dout" is connected to "pin_io" otherwise it goes hi-impedance 'Z'.

when u want to read the pin use "pin_io", when u want to write use "pin_Dout"

```
Entity Main is
  port (pin_io : inout std_logic);
End Main;

Architecture Behavioral of Main is
        signal  pin_Dout : std_logic;
        signal  pin_we  : std_logic := '0'; 
Begin

    pin_io <= pin_Dout when pin_we='1' else 'Z'; -- when pin_we='0';

End Behavioral;
```